# Did Walker ever show up behind the bad guy?

Tags: walker-texas-ranger

So I was sitting in the bathroom when the theme song to Walker, Texas Ranger popped into my head.  The line “If you’re in Texas look behind you, because that’s where the ranger’s going to be.”  It got me thinking if Walker **does** ever sneak up or appear behind a bad guy in the series, and I honestly can’t remember and have no idea how I would search for that.

So, in keeping with the theme song for the show, did Walker ever actually sneak up **behind** a bad guy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Walker Texas Ranger routinely approaches bad guys from behind. I think it's used to show Walker as always getting the drop on them and surprising them. I am going to use a clip from Conan O'Brien that I found on Youtube to illustrate this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ez0rTYKq0h4&feature=related As you can see Walker comes up from behind to surprise a man caught in a bear trap and also jumps from a plane to land behind a villain in car. But it is a little puzzling since the last clip clearly shows that Walker could just as easily have an advantage by letting the bad guys sneak up on him.